# Sind "damit' und "sodass" total gleich?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Eine kurze Frage: sind "damit" und "sodass" komplett austauschbar, oder gibt es Fälle, wo man das Eine oder das Andere nutzen muss?

Comment: Wenn man der Handlung keine Absicht zuschreiben kann (z.B. dem Wetter), muß es *sodass* heißen. Bei Menschen kann je nach dem Kontext *damit* oder *sodass* notwendig sein.

Answer (score 6):

Die beiden Wörter bedeuten nicht dasselbe. Als Konjunktion liegt der Unterschied in der Intention. *Damit* erläutert den Sinn eines eingesetzten Mittels. *Sodass* erläutert hingegen das Ergebnis:

> Sie sprach langsam, damit man ihr leicht folgen konnte. *(Innensicht; die Intention ist bekannt)*
>
> Sie sprach langsam, sodass man ihr leicht folgen konnte. *(reine Außenansicht)*
>
> Sie sprach langsam, damit man ihr leicht folgen konnte, sodass wir aber nicht vorankamen.

Außerdem gibt es noch *damit* als Präpositionaladverb. In dieser Funktion kann es natürlich niemals durch *sodass* ersetzt werden.

> Das habe ich damit gemeint.